# Selenium python multithreaded browsers don't work

Tags: webdriver

I have a problem with selenium webdriver. I use many browsers (multithreading from Qthread), the task is that in order for elements to be found or clicks on them to be made, the browser tab must be active, or my program does not work. I'm use ChromeDriver

```py
class Main(object):
     def __init__(self, driver, *args):
         self.driver = driver
         self.args = [i for i in args]
     def run(self):
         # My code...
         ...
```

I tried to use switching to the active tab

```py
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.current_window_handle) # Without success
```

```py
self.driver.execute_script("window.focus();")
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].focus();", self.driver.find_element("by tag", "body")
```

None of this helped me.